# Nexus3 Configure LDAP with API

Tags: groovy, nexus

I'm currently trying to write a script to configure LDAP on my Nexus 3 instance. I've taken a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/nexus-users/LSUEtL9Z5yo/VK97W1OjBQAJ) post and i'm running into some errors and I think it's just me not understanding Groovy that well.

Here's what I've tried.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.persist.*
import org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.persist.entity.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def ldap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args)
def manager = container.lookup(LdapConfigurationManager.class.name)

manager.addLdapServerConfiguration(
  new LdapConfiguration(
    name: ldap.name,
    connection: new Connection(
      host: new Connection.Host(Connection.Protocol.ldap, ldap.host, ldap.port),
      maxIncidentsCount: 3,
      connectionRetryDelay: 300,
      connectionTimeout: 15,
      searchBase: 'dc=example,dc=com',
      authScheme: 'simple',
      systemPassword: 'systemPassword',
      systemUsername: 'systemUsername'
    ),
    mapping: new Mapping(
      ldapGroupsAsRoles: true,
      emailAddressAttribute: 'mail',
      userIdAttribute: 'sAMAccountName',
      userMemberOfAttribute: 'memberOf',
      userObjectClass: 'user',
      userPasswordAttribute: 'userPassword',
      userRealNameAttribute: 'cn',
      userBaseDn: '(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=Devs,ou=someOU,ou=anotherOU,dc=example,dc=com'
    )
  )
)
```

When i use the provision.sh script provided in the complex-script examples I get:

```
      "name" : "ldapConfig",
      "result" : "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\n
Script8.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class ldapConfiguration \n 
@ line 10, column 3.\n    new ldapConfiguration(\n^\n\n1 error\n"
```

It really bothers me it can't resolve the class...
Now, I'm not sure how to provide the JSON object for args. I've instead tried to put a JSON block directly into JsonSlurper().parseText() like this:

```
ldap = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"host: localhost", "port: 389"}')
```

This produces same error as above.

Here is a snippet from the provision.sh is where invoke the addUpdateScript.groovy script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# A simple example script that publishes a number of scripts to the Nexus Repository Manager
# and executes them.

# fail if anything errors
set -e
# fail if a function call is missing an argument
set -u

username=admin
password=admin123

# add the context if you are not using the root context
host=http://localhost:8081

    # add a script to the repository manager and run it
    function addAndRunScript {
      name=$1
      file=$2
      # using grape config that points to local Maven repo and Central Repository , default grape config fails on some downloads although artifacts are in Central
      # change the grapeConfig file to point to your repository manager, if you are already running one in your organization
      groovy -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true -Dgrape.config=grapeConfig.xml addUpdatescript.groovy -u "$username" -p "$password" -n "$name" -f "$file" -h "$host"
      printf "\nPublished $file as $name\n\n"
      curl -v -X POST -u $username:$password --header "Content-Type: text/plain" "$host/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/$name/run"
      curl -v -X GET -u $username:$password "$host/service/siesta/rest/v1/script/$name"
      printf "\nSuccessfully executed $name script\n\n\n"
    }

    printf "Provisioning Integration API Scripts Starting \n\n" 
    printf "Publishing and executing on $host\n"

    addAndRunScript ldapConfig ldapConfig.groovy
```

Am I using the wrong class name? *LdapConfiguration*.  When I loaded this into IntelliJ I found ldapConfig but it didn't work either.  Not sure how to dig into the javadoc to get more details out of the libraries.

Comment: That's not valid json, try; `ldap = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"host": "localhost", "port": 389}')`

Comment: Ah good catch, i didn't see that.  Made the change here's what was returned.   

result" : "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\nScript10.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class ldapConfiguration \n @ line 10, column 3.

Comment: Sure you've got `new LdapConfiguration` and not with a lower case `l` as the first letter?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks a ton.  You wouldn't happen to know what mapping attribute is for the User Filter?

Comment: it's ldapFilter per the javadoc.  @tim_yates, if you want to put your comment up as an answer i'll mark it accepted.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Good luck! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have

```
new ldapConfiguration(
```

Where you need to have

```
new LdapConfiguration(
```

On line 10 of your script